# Django Page not found (404) No order item matching the query was found

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django and doing my first serious project
Why Django returns the error:

```
"Page not found (404) No order item matching the query"?
```

[image]

application view orders
The DataMixin class is used to generate the contents of the main menu. It is used in almost all other views of my application, so it seems to me that the problem is clearly not in it

view
queryset returns the expected set, despite the fact that Django writes in error

```
\<QuerySet \[\<OrderItem: 31\>, \<OrderItem: 32\>, \<OrderItem: 33\>, \<OrderItem: 34\>\]\>
```

```
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = OrderItem.objects.filter(order_id=self.kwargs['order_id'])
    print(queryset)
    return queryset
```

```
class OrderDetail(DataMixin, DetailView):
    model = Order
    template_name = 'orders/order_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'order'
    pk_url_kwarg = 'order_id'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        c_def = self.get_user_context()
        return context | c_def | {'title': 'Заказ'}

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = OrderItem.objects.filter(order_id=self.kwargs['order_id'])
        return queryset
```

main_urls
I suspect Django doesn't see my url for some reason.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('home.urls', namespace='home')),
    path('cart/', include('cart.urls', namespace='cart')),
    path('orders/', include('orders.urls', namespace='orders')),
    path('users/', include('users.urls', namespace='users')),
]
```

urls

```
app_name = 'orders'

urlpatterns = [
    path('order/<int:order_id>/', OrderDetail.as_view(), name='order_detail'),
    path('create/', OrderCreateView.as_view(), name='order_create'),
]
```

models

```
class Order(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Логин')
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Имя')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Фамилия')
    email = models.EmailField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name='Адрес')
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=20,
                                   verbose_name='Почтовый индекс')
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Город')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Создан')
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='Обновлен')
    paid = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Оформлен')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)
        verbose_name = 'Заказ'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Заказы'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Order {self.id}'

    def get_total_cost(self):
        total_cost = self.items.aggregate(total_cost=Sum('price'))[
            'total_cost']
        return total_cost or 0


class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order,
                              related_name='items',
                              on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product,
                                related_name='order_items',
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.id}'

    def get_cost(self):
        return self.price * self.quantity
```

template

```
<a class="link-secondary" href={% url 'orders:order_detail' order_id %}>Изменить</a>
```

I tried swapping urls, but it didn't help.
I tried to change `{%url %}`, but an error occurred

Comment: Does the Order item with the id of 59 exist in the database? Based on the raised exception the URL is matched correctly but your program cannot find the item in the database - hence you get a 404.

Comment: Yes there is. In get_queryset I get the elements associated with this object